# D language, Eclipse, compiling accross project

Tags: eclipse, compilation, linker, project, d

So I picked up learning the D language, and I use Eclipse. The following question may seem  naive, and probably apply to others languages as well ... Let's say I'm a small-time developer. Anyway :

I made a few simple projects. One of them (P) contains a class (C) that I'd like to reuse in another project (P'). I could of course copypasta it in P', quick and dirty. Now let's say I wanna go clean and do some "maintain once, reuse many". I'm not even sure what the proper terminology would be, something along the lines of "linking" maybe ? I learned that in college in the last century, IDEs were sci-fi back then ...

Question : how do I tell Eclipse "Please compile project P' taking into account the source file C.d that is located in the folder for project P" ?

Comment: The easiest way is, IMHO, to share a common folder where your reusable modules are.

Answer (score 0):

you may just be able to say this project depends on that other project in properties

otherwise you add the source folder of P (where the C.d is) to the include path of project P' and add the correct binary path and library in P to the libpath of P'

you then tell eclipse to compile a library from P which will get placed in the bin folder in P